# Snort PCAP file analysing doesn't write to alert file

Tags: snort, pcap

I'm using snort in my ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine. This is how I installed snort.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install snort
```

I haven't change `/etc/snort/snort.conf` or rules file. They remain as the default and I did PCAP reading using following command.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/snort -d -l /var/log/snort -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -r /home/navarathna/Downloads/cap2.pcap
```

The PCAP file is successfully read and a snort.log file is created, but the size of that file is 0 bytes. When I installed snort, there was no alert file in /var/log/snort directory. So I created one and gave owner permission for snort as following.

```
sudo chown snort.snort alert
```

After the PCAP reading, both `snort.log` and `alert` files have no content (Although the snort.log modified date changes to the last read date and time). Their sizes are 0 bytes. What am I doing wrong here?? Do I need to do some additional changes for rules/snort.conf files?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that snort does not write the alert log when processing a pcap file, however it should write the correct packet capture log (e.g. `/var/log/snort/snort.log.1502097194`).

Since it does not write the alert log, you can get instead get snort to write the alert log messages to syslog using the flag `-s` (or event log in Windows using `-E`) e.g.:

```
snort -s -l /var/log/snort/ -r /pcaps/example.pcap -c /etc/snort/snort.conf
```

You should then see alerts in syslog e.g.:

```
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/messages
Aug  7 09:08:05 snort snort: [1:2101919:23] GPL FTP CWD overflow attempt [Classification: Attempted Administrator Privilege Gain] [Priority: 1] {TCP} 142.167.88.44:61383 -> 192.168.5.122:21
```

In your case, it is likely the `snort.log` contains no data because there were no alerts triggered. You should be able to confirm this, either by reviewing the syslog or in the summary report afterwards e.g.:

```
Action Stats:
     Alerts:            1 (  5.263%)
     Logged:            1 (  5.263%)
     Passed:            0 (  0.000%)
```